# Question About Automatically set method parameters

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, arguments

There are dictionary and methods.

```
ALL_DIC = {"A":"a", "B":"b", "C":"c", "D":"d", "E":"e"}

def something(A=None, B=None, D=None):
    print(A,B,D)

something(**ALL_DIC)
```

The following error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/crawl_master/nolja.py", line 186, in <module>
    something(**ALL_DIC)
TypeError: something() got an unexpected keyword argument 'C'
```

So I used the followings, 
but I don't like it. I'd like to know if there is a better way or library.

```
import inspect
args, _, _, values = inspect.getargspec(something)
for key in list(ALL_DIC.keys()):
    if key not in args:
        del ALL_DIC[key]

something(**ALL_DIC)
```

I'd like some advice. Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much easier way to do it is to make `something` accept variable keyword arguments:

```
def something(A=None, B=None, D=None, **kwargs):
    print(A,B,D)
```

so that any additional keyword arguments passed to `something` will be accepted (and ignored, if you don't use `kwargs`).